# Doubt on presumably divergent series with primes

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers, divergent-series

I am wondering if my reasoning is correct.

I want to determine if the following series converges or not:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(\ln p_n)^2}
\end{equation}
where $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime number.
I am aware that the series of the reciprocals of the prime numbers diverges, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{p_n}=\infty
\end{equation}
Since we also have that for any $\alpha>0$
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x^\alpha}=0
\end{equation}
then, for all $\alpha>0$,
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^\alpha}<\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(\ln k)^2}
\end{equation}
Now, the tricky part is the one I am unsure about. Can I just conclude that the original series diverges by using the last result with the $k$'s replaced by the primes and setting $\alpha$ to $1$? I guess it's a stupid question but I am missing something here. Thank you!

Comment: For every $n$, $$\frac{1}{(\ln p_n)^2}\geqslant\frac{1}{p_n}.$$ Can you show this and apply it to your question?

Comment: Damn. I needed that sequence to be in $l^2$ :D

Comment: ?? Which sequence? Why?

Comment: $1/\ln p_n$... I'm just playing around with primes, but I've found a workaround...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to prove that $\ln^2x < x$ for all $x>1$, since this gives you
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac1{\ln^2 p_n} > \sum_{n=1}^N \frac1{p_n} \stackrel{N\to\infty}\longrightarrow \infty$$
To show this see that $\ln^2 1 = 0 < 1$ and
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \ln^2 x = 2\frac{\ln x}x < 1$$

Comment: $\ln x < x^{1/2}$ , I got it. Thanks!