# Series of Prime Numbers involving logs

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, divergent-series

Maybe my question is too vague, but here it goes:

Is it possible to equal a series over prime numbers that has a log in its denominator (for example,

$$\sum_p \frac{1}{p \log p}$$

$$\sum_p \frac{1}{\sqrt{p} \log p}$$

$$\sum_p \frac{1}{ \log p}$$

) to something "useful" as a series over all natural numbers or an expansion involving elementary functions? I know that some of these examples diverge, so my question would be somewhat equivalent to:

Is there any way to expand these series to anything unrelated to prime numbers? If so, how? Is there any general method to treat with that logs?

Thank you.

**Edit:** After some work with the second series, I have concluded that it is equal to

$$\log \prod_p \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{p}\log{p}}} + K$$

For a fixed constant $K$. The problem is that those logs prevent me from treating the product as an Euler Product nor translating it to a Dirichlet's Series

Comment: How many of those are infinite?  For the first, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1231700/convergence-behavior-of-sum-p-frac1p-log-p-and-generalization while for the second and third, you can adapt  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128884/doubt-on-presumably-divergent-series-with-primes

Comment: @Henry Thank you for pointing out that fact!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [Abel's Summation Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula).

It is a main tool in Number Theory to obtain asymptotic behaviours and more about these types of series.